# How Can This Stickman Be Made to Be Interactive?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

So, I need to make the stick-man movable by a user-input. When the user clicks on a part (Head, hands, feet and posterior) and he should move, and have no idea how to go about this.. 
If possible, there also needs to be a confine around the character, likely rectangular, so that there is a limit to how far each part can be pulled.
See below for my code;

```
// Created by Charlie Carr - (28/11/17 - /11/17)
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.applet.Applet;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.geom.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    //Imports complete

    //Suppress warning about undeclared static final serialVersionUID field in VS Code
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Animator extends JPanel {
            public static class AnimatorWindow extends JPanel {
                    public void paint(Graphics page) {
                            setBackground(Color.gray);
                            setForeground(Color.white);
                            super.paintComponent(page);
                            page.drawString("Stickmen Animation Station", 150, 15);
                            //draw the head
                            //x1, y1, x2, y2
                            page.drawOval(90, 60, 20, 20);
                            // draw the body
                            page.drawLine(100, 80, 100, 110);
                            // draw the hands
                            page.drawLine(100, 90, 80, 105);
                            page.drawLine(100, 90, 120, 105);
                            //draw the legs, he hasn't a leg to stand on..
                            page.drawLine(100, 110, 85, 135);
                            page.drawLine(100, 110, 115, 135);
                    }
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    AnimatorWindow displayPanel = new AnimatorWindow();

                    JPanel content = new JPanel();
                    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    content.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    //declare window size
                    int x = 480;
                    int y = 240;

                    JFrame window = new JFrame("GUI");
                    window.setContentPane(content);
                    window.setSize(x, y);
                    window.setLocation(101, 101);
                    window.setVisible(true);

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MouseListener`to deal with mouse events.

Also, you should override the `paintComponent()` method instead of `paint()`, because `paint()` also paints the border and other stuff.

```
public static class AnimatorWindow extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    public AnimatorWindow(){
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        //add the listener
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        //You should not alter the Graphics object passed in
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) page.create();

        //draw your stuff with g
        g.drawString("Stickmen Animation Station", 150, 15);
        .......

        //finish
        g.dispose();
    }


    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        //implement your clicking here
        //Use e.getX() and e.getY() to get the click position
    }
}
```

For more on swing events, check [this site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

**EDIT**: Your problem also includes animation, and you can use a `javax.swing.Timer` to do that.